# How to download just one package from a PPA?

Tags: 14.04, ppa

I would like to download the `project-x` package for Trusty from a PPA to replace the one supplied with the system. How I can download it (as a DEB file, for example) which I can then install from?

I don't want to add the PPA to my software sources as I do not want to upgrade all the other packages in that PPA.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to provide more details; it's not clear to me what you're asking.

There's no need to install all of the packages from a PPA; simply add the PPA using `apt-add-repository` and install the relevant package using `apt-get`.

Are you concerned that it depends on other packages from the PPA that you don't want to be installed? Package management was created for a reason, and I don't think going out of your way to not install listed dependencies for a package would be advisable.

Is it that you have installed some other packages form the PPA that you don't want to upgrade? Then that's completely solvable, as long as the desired package is OK with the current versions of the packages you don't want to upgrade. Simply freeze the package as described in this question: [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/q/18654/94891)

The Ubuntu Apps and Launchpad websites normally provides downloads for listed PPAs. In case you want Trusty's Project X, [this is the link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/project-x/).

Comment: I do not want Software Updater to replace the currently installed packages with the many from this ppa. I only want to replace the installed project-x package with the one from this ppa. I do not want to freeze/hold the other packages as I still want them to be updated with new versions from Trusty repos when supplied. PS I've found a new version of a Debian .deb for project-x which installs Ok & runs project-x OK.

Comment: @JohnRose Oh, OK; I see. I'm a bit of a n00b, so I don't understand: why would Software Updater replace the currently installed packages with ones from the PPA? Wouldn't they have to be installed explicitly, or via `apt-get` to fulfill some dependency of `project-x`?

Comment: Software Updater replace the currently installed packages with ones from this ppa because the ones from this ppa would most  likely be newer versions, otherwise there would be no point in having a ppa.

Comment: @JohnRose Ah, OK.